# cugraph create NoneType

Tags: python, networkx, dask, rapids, cudf

I tried to create a Graph from a dask_cudf DataFrame, but the Graph get Nonetype without error Message. I tried it with the same data set also with a pandas dataframe. Then I tried it with three sample edges. Each time a NoneType object.
However, if I use the Karate dataset, everything works. I perform the exact same steps three times. The column types are also the same

## From_dask_edgelist

```
cluster = LocalCUDACluster()
client = Client(cluster)
Comms.comms.initialize(p2p=True)

edges = dask.read_csv('.csv')
edges = edges.groupby(['Source','Target'])['retweet_from'].count()
edges = edges.to_frame(name="weight").reset_index()
edges = edges.map_partitions(cudf.DataFrame.from_pandas)
G = cugraph.Graph().from_dask_cudf_edgelist(edges,
                                            source = 'Source',
                                            destination = 'Target',
                                            edge_attr = 'weight')

G.__class__
NoneType
```

## From_Pandas_edgelist Karate Dataset

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rapidsai/cugraph/branch-22.10/datasets/karate.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url,delimiter=' ', header=None, names=["0", "1", "2"],
dtype={"0": "int32", "1": "int32","2": "float32"})

G = cugraph.Graph()
G.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='0', destination='1',edge_attr='2', renumber=False)

G.__class__
cugraph.structure.graph_classes.Graph
```

## From_Pandas_edgelist

```
edges = pd.read_csv('.csv')
edges = edges.groupby(['Source','Target'])['retweet_from'].count()
edges = edges.to_frame(name="weight").reset_index()
edges['Source'] = edges['Source'].astype("int32")
edges['Target'] = edges['Target'].astype("int32")
edges['weight'] = edges['weight'].astype("float32")
edges.dtypes
Source      int32
Target      int32
weight    float32
dtype: object

G = cugraph.Graph()
G = G.from_pandas_edgelist(edges,source = 'Source',destination = 'Target',edge_attr = 'weight', renumber=False)

G.__class__
NoneType
```

## From_Pandas_edgelist with three Edges

```
data = [[1, 3,3], [2, 1,1], [3, 1, 7]]
edges = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Source', 'Target', 'weight'])
edges['Source'] = edges['Source'].astype("int32")
edges['Target'] = edges['Target'].astype("int32")
edges['weight'] = edges['weight'].astype("float32")
G = cugraph.Graph()
G = G.from_pandas_edgelist(edges,source = 'Source',
                                            destination='Target',edge_attr = 'weight', renumber=False)
G.__class__
NoneType
```

Comment: in the `From_dask_edgelist` example.  Why not use dask_cudf?

Comment: Do you mean i should use cudf_dask.read_csv? I tried this too, but still get an Nonetype

Answer (score 1):

**Example 1:  From_dask_edgelist**
you need to add "edges['weight'] = edges['weight'].astype("float32")"  so that the dtype of weight is correct.  otherwise the `from_dask_cudf_edgelist` will throw and error and return None

**Example 3:  From_Pandas_edgelist**
**Example 4:  From_Pandas_edgelist with three Edges**
This will currently not work since 'from_pandas_edgelist' returns None (PR mentioned above fixes that).   If you change
`G = G.from_pandas_edgelist(edges,source = 'Source',destination = 'Target',edge_attr = 'weight', renumber=False)`  
to be just 
`G.from_pandas_edgelist(edges,source = 'Source',destination = 'Target',edge_attr = 'weight', renumber=False)`
then it will work

Comment: Thanks, the hint for Example 1 does not work. I get still no error and a None. But the tip for from_pandas_edgelist works

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the cuGraph functions can be pipelined.
The call `from_dask_cudf_edgelist`  return `None`

The perferred way is:

```
G = cugraph.Graph()
G.from_dask_cudf_edgelist(edges,
                           source = 'Source',
                           destination = 'Target',
                           edge_attr = 'weight')
```

Then G.**class** will work

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I tried this too and I still get   a  NoneType

Comment: I have added three more example